# Setting up repetition in lines()

Tags: r, plot, lines, repeat

I am trying to create a 'before and after' line chart which shows results of blood tests before and after an operation. I have 307 pairs of data so need to get the lines function to plot a line for each of the 307 columns in the matrix of data created from pre- and post-operative data (one column: one patient). So I tried this:

```
ylabel<-"Platelet count (millions/ml)"
preoptpk<-c(100,101,102,103,104,105)
postoptpk<-c(106,107,108,109,110,111) 
preoptpk<-t(matrix(preoptpk))
postoptpk<-t(matrix(postoptpk)) 
preoptpk 
postoptpk
beforeandafterdata<-rbind(preoptpk, postoptpk) 
beforeandafterdata
ylimits<-c(0.8*min(beforeandafterdata,na.rm=TRUE),1.15*max(beforeandafterdata, na.rm=TRUE)) 
ylimits
plot(beforeandafterdata[,1], type = "l", col = "black", xlim = c(0.9, 2.1), 
           ylim = ylimits, ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)
title(ylab=ylabel, cex.lab=1.4)
axis(1,at=1:2,lab=c("Preop.","Postop."),cex.axis=1.5)
axis(2,labels=TRUE) 
x<-c(1*2:6) 
x
lines(beforeandafterdata[,x],type="l",col="black", 
           xlim=c(0.9,2.1),ylim=ylimits,ann=FALSE)
```

..and nothing happened.

I don't understand why I can't use x<-c(1*2:307) since when I manually define x as 2 then 3 then 4 then 5 then 6 it works fine:

```
x <- 2 x
 lines(beforeandafterdata[,x],type="l",col="black",xlim=c(0.9,2.1),ylim=ylimits,ann=FALSE)
x <-3 x
lines(beforeandafterdata[,x],type="l",col="black",xlim=c(0.9,2.1),ylim=ylimits,ann=FALSE)
x <-4 x
lines(beforeandafterdata[,x],type="l",col="black",xlim=c(0.9,2.1),ylim=ylimits,ann=FALSE)
x<-5 x
lines(beforeandafterdata[,x],type="l",col="black",xlim=c(0.9,2.1),ylim=ylimits,ann=FALSE)
x<-6 x
lines(beforeandafterdata[,x],type="l",col="black",xlim=c(0.9,2.1),ylim=ylimits,ann=FALSE)
x<-c(1*2:6)
```

Any help how I can get this to work? Since I have several variables and manually plotting 307 lines for each will be v. time consuming. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to stay close to your example, you need to use `xy.coords` within `lines`.

```
plot(beforeandafterdata[,1],type="l",col="black",xlim=c(0.9,2.1),ylim=ylimits,
     ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE) 
title(ylab=ylabel, cex.lab=1.4) 
axis(1,at=1:2,lab=c("Preop.","Postop."),cex.axis=1.5)
axis(2,labels=TRUE) 
x<-c(1*2:6) 
x 
lapply(x, function(x){
lines(xy.coords(x=c(1, 2), y=c(beforeandafterdata[,x])), type="l", col="black", 
      xlim=c(0.9,2.1),ylim=ylimits,ann=FALSE)
})
```

lapply is needed to prevent one line being joined to the next

Comment: fwiw, `lapply(x, function(x) lines(beforeandafterdata[,x],...))` will work as well.

Comment: @Justin - that's much better. Thanks

Comment: Thank you v much you two! /Owain.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for loop` to do this.  e.g.:

```
for (x in 2:6) {
  lines(beforendafterdata[,x], ...)
}
```

Or you can use the `reshape2` and `ggplot2` packages.  First `melt` your data into a long format that `ggplot2` likes:

```
library(reshape2)
beforeandafter_melted <- melt(beforeandafterdata)
```

Then plot away.  You don't need the `color` argument, but the `group` is important to force individual lines to be drawn.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(beforeandafter_melted, aes(x=Var1, y=value, color=factor(Var2), group=Var2)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Where `Var1` is the row (1 or 2) and `Var2` is the column (1 to 6) from your initial matrix `beforeandafterdata`.

Also, why have you written `x <- c(1*2:307)`?  This is no different than `2:307` (unless you're trying to force numeric conversion, but that isn't the way to go about it).

```
all.equal(c(1*2:307), 2:307)
# [1] TRUE
```